# How do I annotate $this inside callback function

Tags: php, laravel

It's not a Laravel question despite the code example is from Laravel!

So I have this part of code

```
class MacroServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Collection::macro('method_name', function () {
            return $this->map(function ($item) {
                //...do something;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is that `$this` does not belong to `MacroServiceProvider` but to the `Collection` and my IDE and phpstan show me errors, of course.

EDIT: The question wasn't clear. IDE thinks that `$this` is `MacroServiceProvider` but the callback executed in `Collection`. So when it's executed `$this` will be `Collection`. What I want to achieve is to instruct code validators that $this inside callback is `Collection` instance.

Is it possible to annotate `$this` and tell that it belongs to `Collection` instance?

P.S. PHP version is 7.3 IDE is PHPStorm but I reckon it doesn't matter.

P.P.S. The code works just fine. It's only about phpstan validation.

Comment: go on like this: `function($item) use ($this){}`

Comment: Last time I looked into this with PhpStorm it wasn't possible. Not sure if that changed now. It does really depend on your IDE though.

Comment: Importent question - which php version?

Comment: Your not allowed to put `$this` into the `use` statement, but you can use `$that` as in `$that=$this`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix why not Closure::bind ?

Comment: @kuh-chan - in 5.3 that was the only option, not sure what version they have but that will work in any that have support for closures.  Also in 5.3 this did not exist within closures.

Comment: @tuytoosh doing `use ($this)` will change the context. So $this will be `MacroServiceProvider `. It's not what I want.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Could you please give more details on `Closure::bind`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php

Comment: Sorry, but it's still not what I want. I don't need to change the context.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to support a docblock for `$this` - it does work for PhpStorm, not sure about phpstan:

```
class MacroServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Collection::macro('method_name', function () {
            /** @var Collection $this */
            return $this->map(function ($item) {
                //...do something;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

However keep in mind that any call of that monkey-patched Collection's method will lead to the same issue - neither IDE nor analyzers will know about it's existence. I personally would avoid these tactics - I'd rather use composition to emded Collection to some other object - be it your custom collection class or some container that needs your collection. But that's not Laravel-ish way of doing things of course.

**UPDATE**. Found some nice wrapper for phpstan - [larastan](https://github.com/nunomaduro/larastan) - which "supports Laravel's beautiful magic". It may be of help.

Comment: Thank you Ivan. Unfortunately it doesn't work for phpstan. I'm aware about how bad that code is and am going to get rid of it in the future but have to support it for now because a lot of usage.

Comment: FYI, a lot of the problems around using dynamic, or "monkey patched", methods can be solved by packages that dynamically create the docblocks and method stubs in IDE helper files (like `barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper`). It's not perfect, but it does eliminate a few of the tradeoffs you would otherwise be making by using techniques like this

Answer (score 0):

Another way to provide hints to your IDE is to have a file of method stubs. It might look similar to this for a macro created on the Collection class:

```
<?php


namespace Illuminate\Support{ 

    /**
     * 
     *
     */ 
    class Collection{
        /**
         *
         *
         * @return Collection
         */ 
        public function method_name() {}
    }
}
```

This is one of the techniques that packages like [laravel-ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) use to provide hints to IDEs about a lot of the dynamic method calls and dependency injection in Laravel.

For reference, here is a full example of the `_ide_helper.php` file that it generates, taken from their readme: https://gist.github.com/barryvdh/5227822

According to the title it should at least work for Netbeans, PhpStorm, and Sublime Text 2 CodeIntel.

Files full of method stubs are how IDEs like PhpStorm can have code hints (IntelliSense) for the standard libraries that are compiled into the PHP runtime. The difference is that those stubs are located somewhere in the IDEs installation directory instead of your project directory.